# Replace image masks on canvas issue

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a car image and i need to blink effect on its tyres and glasses with the help of canvas.

For that i used canvas draw image function and it is working fine but problem is when i hover on tyre tab tyres should be blink and when i hover on glass tab glasses should be blink but it happens only once.

Like if i hover first on tyre tab then it blinks using blink function but when i mouseout and hover on glass tab this time also blink effect but on tyres(on first hover tab) not on glasses, because in my code it draw image once until that has different functions for both.

I searched many answers on online but unable to achieve that. I already used clearRect function but i think by this my first image is not removing.

I am creating an image with this code:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);                   
context.save();
context.drawImage(mask, 0, 0); //mask
context.fillStyle= ""; //fill color style
context.fillStyle= "#6600ee"; //fill color style
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
context.drawImage(shadow, 0, 0); //shadow
context.drawImage(glossreflection, 0, 0); //reflection                  
context.restore();
```

and try to remove on mouse out By:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

I put alerts also that all are working but i am not understanding about this issue.

Comment: you should put more code so that we see how you handle the mouse.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for us so we have a little more to chew on.

Comment: I haven't fiddle account and main code i already copied sir